# Backslashes breaking string in PHP

Tags: php, string, string-formatting

I have an issue. I'm trying to write a string with ASCII text like this: '/\'. But whenever I do that the backslash screws up the code by canceling out the quote defining it a string therefore screwing it up. Is there anyway to cancel out the backslash so it doesn't cancel out the quote? Thanks guys!

Comment: can you show us the string with quoting as you have it now?

Comment: When a backslash appears immediately before a quote in a string in PHP, it's escaping that character so it won't be the closing quote. You need to escape the backslash with another. `\\'`

Comment: @WEBjuju My output is in a comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` is special character, that says: 'The next character has special meaning'.

So if you want to dispaly `\` you should write... `\\` to get one `\` in output

Comment: I tried that. The original string looks like this: ''\/\/'' and the modified string looks like this "'\\/\\/'" but I got this output "//"

Answer (score 0):

A great solution when writing stuff like that is HEREDOC. Inside a heredoc block you don't need to worry about escaping anything, it will just be text.

For example:

```
echo <<<TEXT

/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\

TEXT;
```

There is one catch. PHP will break if you don't align the echo at the start of the line, or if the TEXT; is not aligned at the start of the line.

Heredoc can also be assigned to a variable, like so:

```
$var = <<<SOME_MORE_TEXT

/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\

SOME_MORE_TEXT;
```

Finally, HEREDOC preserves tabs and spaces. Which also might come in handy when doing ASCII art.

Refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for more information.

Comment: where is that example the OP indicated they put in the answer section?  i guess i assumed this solution was the OP putting their example in an answer.  shrug.  my new one is much less confusing.

Comment: Indeed it is! Owned it!

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful to show what you have tried, but this will produce the exact output you requested (as shown by SO)

```
echo '\'/\\' . "'\n" ;
```

'/\'

It should also give you an idea of how backslash escaping works in different types of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to escape the final one when using single quotes.

```
$var = 'backslash\backslash\backslash\\';
// output is:
// backslash\backslash\backslash\
```

Comment: what i don't get is that if the op's example is just $var = '\/\/'; It would just come out **\/\/**.  I guess we will be stuck with the mystery since we seem more interested in this than the OP does.